# Using rqt_plot, how to find the topic name?

Tags: rostopic, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in the rqt_plot part of understandingTopic toturial http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics

the topic is

> /turtle1/pose/x

> /turtle1/pose/y

> /turtle1/pose/theta

but I can only find the topic

> /turtle1/pose/

using command

> rostopic list

(and rqt_plot doesn't work when only fill /turtle1/pose/ in the textbox)

where can I find the x/y/theta?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127371/using-rqt_plot,-how-to-find-the-topic-name?/) by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you must use it in this form

> rqt_plot /topic1/field1

To graph multiple fields of a message:

> rqt_plot /topic1/field1:field2:field3

To graph the data all on the same plot:

> $ rqt_plot
> /topic1/field1,/topic2/field2

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-02-08**:
so, how to find the field name?

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-02-08**:
use "$rosmsg show msg_name" or use "$rostopic echo topic_name " to see diffrent fields of msg